# Laraveldaily/Quickadmin routes location

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

Does someone knows where I can find the file location of the routes generated by the quickadmin package?

Thank you very much if answered. I'm quite researching about this for the whole day and doesn't find any resources.

EDIT:
I am referring to the routes generated after you successfully created a new CRUD Controller from the Quickadmin Menu.

Comment: https://github.com/LaravelDaily/quickadmin/blob/master/src/routes.php

Comment: hi @ceejayoz, I am referring to the routes generated when you generate a CRUD Controller from the Quickadmin Menu, not the package-defined routes. Will add edit though to the question.

Comment: @JohnAlvirBismonte It should be in routes.php

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya, as I've mentioned earlier, it is not in the route.php even in the laravel's own route.php

Comment: @JohnAlvirBismonte If you can search on your whole project try to search this line `menu.parent` you will find it in which file it is storing routes

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya, actually I know the file location you are referring to. It is the one mentioned by ceejayoz earlier. It only has the 
/**
 * Package routing file specifies all of this package routes.
 */
so meaning, these are package defined routes, not the routes you've generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @ceejayoz, it took me  a while to understand the logic of the function in the file he mentioned. The routes are dynamically generated by it.